# How to generate dynamic length array in matrix formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I do the following within an array formula like (in Excel 2019)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(A1:A3))
```

This generates an array of 3 numbers like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3})
```

How can I generate a dynamic length array from 1 to N? For example if in A1 I have 5 I can do this:

```
B1=ADDRESS(1,1)&":"& ADDRESS(A1,1)
```

And this will produce

```
B1=A1:A5
```

But if I do the following I get error:

`=SUMPRODUCT(ROW(ADDRESS(1,1)&":"& ADDRESS(A1,1)))`

The expected output would be:

```
= SUMPRODUCT({1,2,3,4,5})
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: `=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,A1)))` --> using of `ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,A1))` idea courtesy ofcourse from @ScottCraner Sir .

Comment: Excellent. You should be put it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above, posting it as an answer:

[image]

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,A1)))
```

---

Initially I was using <kbd>INDIRECT( )</kbd> (as it is a volatile function and should be avoided as much as possible) but the trick with <kbd>ROW( )</kbd> & <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> function learnt from **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir, so the credit goes to Sir.